# Boolean Variable given by a NSMenuItem

Tags: swift, cocoa

I try to define a global boolean variable by a click/unclick on a `NSMenuItem` and indicate the value just before the label with a tick, as currently done in f.lux (cf. picture below).

My menu is currently build as below and I do not find on `NSMenuItem` documentation how to achieve it.

Has someone already done it ?

```
let menu = NSMenu()

menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Autocheck", action: #selector(AppDelegate.autocheck(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))

menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))
statusItem.menu = menu
```

[image: f.lux]

Comment: Look at the `state` property of `NSMenuItem`.

Comment: @maddy It works well ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Not related to your question but `autocheck.state = automount ? .on : .off`

Comment: @AlexisG Instead of editing your question with the answer, post the answer below as an actual answer. I've rolled back your update and posted it below (as community wiki so I don't get credit for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way is to use the `state property` of `NSMenuItem`.
Final code is:

```
let menu = NSMenu()

menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
let autocheck = NSMenuItem(title: "Autocheck", action: #selector(AppDelegate.automount_bool(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")

if automount==true{
    autocheck.state = NSControl.StateValue.on
}else{
    autocheck.state = NSControl.StateValue.off
}

menu.addItem(autocheck)
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))

statusItem.menu = menu
```